# Sending array to controller/model in CI with AJAX

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, model, controller

So basically I have a two item array in javascript that is generated based on which link the user clicks. I am trying to send this array to my controller, and then to the model. The model will look at the array and match one of the items to a certain column/row, and will selectively display data.

I am having issues passing the data from AJAX to my controller.

AJAX code (in a .js file)

```
  $('#youmax-video-list-div').append('<div id="testing1"></div>');

                    $('#concept').click(function(){
                                        console.log(course);
                       $.ajax({
                              url: 'http://localhost:8888/index.php/trial/getValues',
                              type:'POST',
                              dataType: 'json',
                              data:'',
                              error: function(){
                              $('#testing1').append('<p>goodbye world</p>');
                              },
                              success: function(result) {
                              var htmlStr = '';
                              $.each(result, function(a, b){
                                     htmlStr += b.qText + '<br />';
                                     });
                              $('#testing1').append(htmlStr);
                              } // End of success function of ajax form
                              }); // End of ajax call
                       });
```

I am assuming I must do something with the data field, but I dont know the syntax for it.

The console log in chrome comes up with this:

Array[2]
0: "PL8G0kdHFfE3WuyevUDvwSYCZw8mp8LBFA"
1: "PL8G0kdHFfE3V62Jp2ju-PelOaNUkH7xR8"

Controller

```
function getValues(){
    $this->load->model('get_db');
    $data = $this->get_db->getAll();
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
    return $data;  
}
```

Model

```
class Get_db extends CI_Model{
    function getAll(){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM questions");
        return $query->result();
        //returns from this string in the db, converts it into an array

    }
}
```

As I said before, I am really only concerned with getting the data to my controller and my model.
The name of the array is "course". However, that doesnt appear to be so in the console.log. Is that just something chrome does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// **chkval** be the class for elements for the arrays

AJAX function:

```
function ajaxSub(goals)
{
    var theArray = new Array();
    var i=0;
    jQuery('.chkval').each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).prop('checked'))
        {
            theArray[i] = jQuery(this).val();
            i++;
        }
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo site_url('mycontroller/myfunctions');?>',
         type: 'post',
         data: {
             arr: theArray,
             other_id: ''
         },
         datatype: 'json',
         success: function () {
         }
    });
}
```

in the controller:

```
$arr = $this->post('arr');

foreach($arr as $ar)
{
    echo $ar; // prints each element of the array.
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but there are no results. Whenever I use echo and ajax, the error message appears that I set up in the ajax call. However, If i change echo to return, i get the success function, but still nothing is displayed @ReNiShAR

Comment: in the above i just echo it as an example,, you can do anything with the array and return...

Answer (score 0):

Same as above answer but in controller run this code:

```
$arr = $this->input->post('arr');

foreach($arr as $ar)
{

    echo $ar; // prints each element of the array.

}
```